# How do I add custom deviation when using LinearModelFit?

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

I have a set of data in the form a list `S1={{x,y},{x,y}}` etc.

I also have a function that calculates a corrected standard deviation in the y direction for standard deviation in x and y.  That function looks like this:

```
σyP[σy_, U_, I_, δI_] := Sqrt[σy^2 + (U*(2*δI /I))^2];
```

How can I calculate a linear best fit line for my data that takes into account the corrected standard deviation that is calculated by my function?

I would also like to add the error bars to my current plot of the points.

Comment: Use the option `NormFunction[]`.

Comment: `LinearModelFit` doesn't support `NormFunction`, but maybe you can get what you want using the `Weights` option. From the documentation: "With the setting `Weights -> {w1, w2, ...}`, the error variance for $y_i$ is assumed to be $\sigma^2/w_i$. By default, unit weights are used."

Comment: I see the formula but what is a "corrected standard deviation in the y direction for standard deviation in x and y"?  The usual regression model assumes that the x values are fixed and known.  The use of the term "standard deviation in x" seems to imply that x has a random component which doesn't fit (no pun intended) with usual regression models.  Are ${\sigma}y$, $U$, $I$, and ${\delta}I$ parameters to be estimated or known?